# What to do with bloom when dependency unavailable on Debian

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, bloom-release, jessie

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From ROS `Kinetic` [looks like](http://lists.ros.org/pipermail/ros-release/2016-April/004861.html) `Debian` (`Jessie` for Kinetic) will be official supported OS.

I had an issue [when I made a release of a package into Kinetic](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/11445) where one of the dependencies was not yet available on Jessie at that time so that build on ROS buildfarm failed only for Jessie.

Looks like @tfoote fixed it by re-running `bloom`, but what magic with bloom we could use for this kind of problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234632/what-to-do-with-bloom-when-dependency-unavailable-on-debian/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If the dependencies are not available you'll have to do like you did and tell bloom to skip that action.

If you skip an action for a target like debian it needs to be added to the blacklist on the buildfarm so that the buildfarm will not try to repeatedly build.

We are refactoring the buildfarm config to allow a higher level of granularity on the blacklisting: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm_config/pull/41 without that landed we could not easily blacklist a package for debian only. Once that's merged we will be able to do so.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0